# Azure DevOps Server: - Adding a field to a work-item type

Tags: xml, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I have a custom workflow created on our self-hosted Azure DevOps server. Currently, it's based on the XML that defines the Basic workflow apart from a new name and description.

I'm trying to add a field to the epic work-item type called "Contact Person." Using System.AssignedTo as a template, I've added this new field to"

- WIT/FIELDS (as FIELD)
- WIT/FORM/Group/Column/TabGroup/Tab("Features")/LinkColumns (As LinkColumn)
- WIT/FORM/Group/Column/TabGroup/Tab("All Links")/LinkColumns (As LinkColumn)
- WIT/FORM/Group("Planning")/Column (As Control)

I didn't add the custom field to SystemControls because that was causing a parse error. I did try the four above in various combinations. **None** caused errors, but none caused the field to appear when I create a new epic.

I've been up and down the documentation without answers. How do I edit the workflow to add this field? And is there anything like a linter that will tell me if my XML isn't going to do work the way it's supposed to?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the doc: [Add or modify a field to track work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/add-modify-field?view=azure-devops-2019). In your steps:

- *WIT/FIELDS (as FIELD)* - ok
- *WIT/FORM/Group/Column/TabGroup/Tab("Features")/LinkColumns (As LinkColumn)* is not needed
- *WIT/FORM/Group/Column/TabGroup/Tab("All Links")/LinkColumns (As LinkColumn)* is not needed
- *WIT/FORM/Group("Planning")/Column (As Control)* - ok but it applies only to the old form

Additionally, you should add to the WIT/FORM/WebLayout/Page/Section/Group as Control to see it on the web form: [WebLayout and Control elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 1):

> Azure DevOps Server: - Adding a field to a work-item type

The reason for this issue is that:

> **I didn't add the custom field to SystemControls because that was causing a parse error.**

Indeed, the System namespace is used only to define all core system fields that are mandatory for Team Foundation system functions. **Team Foundation Server prevents you from creating your own System.X field** because it might impede Team Foundation Server functionality.

[On-premises XML process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=azure-devops#header-customization):

You can modify select elements within the SystemControls section, such as changing the EmptyText attribute value for the System.Title field. **In general, we recommend you don't customize this section much more than that. For example, you can't remove fields from or add other fields within this section.**

**So, we could not add the custom field under the `SystemControls`. But we need add it under the `Section`**, check following scripts:

```
  <Section>
    <Group Label="Planning">
      <Control Label="Priority" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" />
      <Control Label="ContactTo" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Custom.ContactTo" />
      <Control Label="Start Date" Type="DateTimeControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StartDate" />
      <Control Label="Target Date" Type="DateTimeControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.TargetDate" />
    </Group>
  </Section>
```

The `ContactTo` is my custom label.

Then, we could see it in the custom process:

[image]

Hope this helps.